# paging via graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, paging

i have been working on a new app to display feeds posted from a certain app, which is working fine, however, it only shows 25 results and after that it shows a paging array like so:

```
[paging] => Array
        (
            [previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/100000229028365/home?method=GET&access_token=AAACOrxawWZCgBACwTDcb79QOtboPgAhLGLT4d31vkKEqQTVHgj91a6QGQ9mUFhdpScma4ZCdmpZB7HNnpGj0itAht4oVJqJLyIRMVy4VFnGfQ07WZCKz&limit=25&since=1321212154
            [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/100000229028365/home?method=GET&access_token=AAACOrxawWZCgBACwTDcb79QOtboPgAhLGLT4d31vkKEqQTVHgj91a6QGQ9mUFhdpScma4ZCdmpZB7HNnpGj0itAht4oVJqJLyIRMVy4VFnGfQ07WZCKz&limit=25&until=1321209616
        )
```

i have tried to implament this into my app without success.

can anyone show me an example how to use this to produce pagnation for my app?
pretty stuck now =os

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure all you need to do is take the previous link and do a graph call with that to get the next 25, alternatively the less desirable method would be to change the limit when you do a graph call or if you dont use one when you do a call specify ?limit=100 and this will get 100 results

Comment: In my experience, limit=100 is not working. Facebook is only returning 25 feed items

Comment: Limit=100 should be working. It would be something else in your graph call that is causing it to fail. On one of my apps i actually use limit=350 and that works successfully for everyone who has installed my app.

Comment: it depends on what graph element. sometimes i can do 100, sometimes only 25